# How do you get the inverse Euclid equation for perfect numbers?

Tags: logarithms, inverse

Any number is a perfect number if It's equal to the sum of all Its divisors except itself. For example, 28 is a perfect number because 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28. According to Euclid, the set of all perfect numbers are obtained by the following formula:

```
2^(p-1) * (2^p - 1)
```

Where `p` and `2^p - 1` should be prime.

However, if we use a function like f: P -> N, where P is the set of `2^p - 1` prime numbers, and N is the set of all perfect numbers, how would you obtain the inverse function f^-1: N -> P? For example, f^-1(28) = 3, because:

```
2^2 * (2^3 - 1) = 28
```

Trying to isolate the `p` variable via logarithms seems impossible, so I'm stuck here. Is there any way to solve this?

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: If an even number is of this form, you do not need to isloate anything, just divide the number by $2$ as often as possible. The number of times you can do it is $p-1$. Then, the given expression must be the even number, if it is actually perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to solve the equation $2^{p-1}(2^p-1) = N$ for $p$. While this looks almost hopeless, we can exploit a coincidence by writing the equation as
\begin{align*}
2^p(2^p-1) &= 2N \\
(2^p)^2 - 2^p - 2N &= 0,
\end{align*}
for which the quadratic formula gives the solutions
\begin{align*}
2^p &= \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8N}}{2}.
\end{align*}
Since $2^p$ must be positive, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
2^p &= \frac{1+\sqrt{1+8N}}{2} \\
p &= \log_2 \frac{1+\sqrt{1+8N}}{2} = \log_2 \bigl( 1+\sqrt{1+8N} \bigr) - 1.
\end{align*}
(By the way, these calculations are valid regardless of whether $N$ is a perfect number, whether $p$ is a prime, or indeed whether they are integers at all—they are valid for all real numbers $p$ and $N$.)